# prove that $\frac{1}{h}\int^{h}_{0}F(y)\,dy\to F(+\infty)$ as $h\to +\infty$

Tags: integration, limits

If F is a non-decreasing, right continuous and a bounded function show that 
$$\frac{1}{h}\int^{h}_{0}F(y)\,dy\to F(+\infty)\text{ as }h\to +\infty.$$

Comment: Are you unable to even start solving this? If not, please write up what you have done so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should better be shown from first principles without using L'Hopital rule. 
Define $G(h) = \frac1h \int_0^h F(y) \, dy$.  Since $F$ is bounded and not decreasing, the limit of $F$ when $h\rightarrow \infty$ exists (and is finite, written as $F(+\infty)$.  Now choose some $\epsilon > 0$, and fine large enough $y_\epsilon$ such that $F(y_\epsilon) > F(+\infty) - \epsilon$. Write for $h > y_\epsilon$
\begin{align}
   G(h) &= \frac1h \left( \int_0^{y_\epsilon} F(y)\, dy + \int_{y_\epsilon}^h F(y)\, dy \right) \\
      &\ge \frac{h-y_\epsilon}{h}\cdot \frac{\int_{y_\epsilon}^h F(y)\, dy}{h-y_\epsilon}  \\
   &\ge \frac{h-y_\epsilon}{h} (F(+\infty)-\epsilon)
\end{align} and now letting $h$ go to infinity this approaches $F(+\infty)-\epsilon$. Since this can be done foe any positive $\epsilon$, we are almost done. And, since it is clear the limit cannot be any larger, we are done. (As written, this proof assumes the integrand is never negative. But that problem can be solved in like manner).

Comment: yes it's a great idea to see things thank you, and you're right concerning the non-negativity of the integral since I have as an assumption $0\leq F(y) \leq 1$ thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

As your assumption, we can conclude that $g(h)=\int_0^h F(y)dy$ goes to $\infty$ when $h\rightarrow+\infty$. Otherwise, $\lim_{h\rightarrow+\infty}F(h)=0$ is valid from the convergence of improper integral which is contradict to assumption. So that 
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow+\infty} \frac{\int_0^h F(y)dy}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow+\infty} F(h)=F(+\infty)
$$
In the first equality L'Hospital principle have been used.

Comment: yes I followed the same steps , but I had doubts in calculating the limit of g since F is only right continuous and F(0) can be null.

Answer (score 1):

Use L'hopitals rule in the limit for h->infinity